# Multiple non-related models in one Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am building a blog-style application in Rails 3 where multiple users are able to post some news. After the login (which is realized with "Authlogic") the user values are stored in a own model called e.g. "UserSession". The form for the post contains title, content etc. and the username should be stored with a hidden form.

I think that the two models don't need to be related to each other (by that I mean a `:has_many` - `:belongs_to` relationship) because there isn't any further usage for that information.

Do I really not need this relation? And how could I realize the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Authlogic is it important to remember that the 'UserSession' does not correspond to any database tables (i.e. you would never use a has_many or has_one 'UserSession'). I think the relationship you are looking for is:

```
User has many Posts
Blog belongs to User
```

The reason? It is always a good idea to associate a record with the 'owner' so that the owner can later modify or delete the record. I hope this helps.